# Get all IPs from textfile that are in a file containing all subnets

Tags: regex, ip, subnet

I'm trying to track down a user that once registered in my system. I have his real name and I know that he's from Norway. Since his real name isn't stored anywhere in the system, the only way to trace him down is by using that he's from Norway.

From logs over the last few months I've extracted a list of 2000 IP addresses that certainly includes his IP. this file is called ips.txt, and has one IP per line. The IP's are from everywhere in the world, mainly from the Balkan, South-America and the Middle-East (yes, that is quite a diverse user base).

There are 2000 IP addresses in this file: one per line. Most of these (60% or so) are from Egypt and Tunesia, as users from these countries do not have dedicated IP addresses.

From http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/ I've taken a list containing all subnets from Norway. More specifically: http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/aggregated/no-aggregated.zone (not sure if this list is complete)

---

My question: How can I select all IPs from ips.txt that are within one of the subnets from the zone file?

---

Remarks:

- I am aware this will probably take `#IPs * #subnets` (quadratic) time. I do not really care about efficiency, so long the script is done in about an hour.
- I added the tag Regex, but I have no idea how to parse the IP subnets using regex.
- Everything is IPv4

Comment: It'll certainly **COULD** be a combination of RegEx and something else.  JavaScript would probably work, too.  Any particular language you care to use?

Comment: I'm currently using a very ugly way: IP -> 32 bit int; then test it "(ip >> subnetlength) & (subnet >> subnetlength) == 0". There must be a smarter way, but maybe I'll finish it before someone else comes up with a smart solution. If this is the case, I'll put my own answer in the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible way is to use a GeoIP database, and do queries for each IP address to get the country. You can download these databases locally for free, there're implemented APIs (both network and local) and it would be much simpler to implement.

Comment: I'll look that up!

Comment: https://freegeoip.net/ looks promising! Also the hourly 10k quota is within my limits. This is great! Thank you

Comment: I used maxmind, it has apis for many languages and ipdates the free version local db (which has countries and cities) weekly

Comment: @Jasper If you found my answer useful, please accept it

Comment: Sorry @buld0zzr , I forgot about that :P I haven't looked into the issue yet, but I think the IP database approach will work out well!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (nonfunctional) code that I tried to solve this problem with. I solved my problem by using another IP database, which required less work. I expect that there is only a silly bug in this script somewhere, so I think someone may eventually be helped by this in the future!

```
var fs = require('fs');

var iparray = fs.readFileSync('ips.txt').toString().split("\n");
var subnets = fs.readFileSync('norway.txt').toString().split("\n");
var ips = [];
var ipsubnets = [];
var answer = [];

// IP to 32-bit int
for (var i=0; i<iparray.length; i++) {
    if (iparray[i] != '') {
        var ipwub = iparray[i].split(".")
        var ip = (ipwub[0] << 24) + (ipwub[1] << 16) + (ipwub[2] << 8) + (ipwub[3] << 0)
        ips.push (ip);
    }
}
//console.log (ips)

// Subnet to 32-bit int
for (var i=0; i<subnets.length; i++) {
    if (subnets[i] != '') {
        var subnetarray = subnets[i].split("/");
        var subnetsize = subnetarray[1] << 0;
        var ipwub = subnetarray[0].split(".")
        var ip = (ipwub[0] << 24) + (ipwub[1] << 16) + (ipwub[2] << 8) + (ipwub[3] << 0)
        ipsubnets.push ([ip,subnetsize]);
    }
}
//console.log (ipsubnets)

// Check it
iploopy: for (var j=0; j<ipsubnets.length; j++) {
    for (var i=0; i<ips.length; i++) {
        var ip = ips[i];
        var subnet = ipsubnets[j][0];
        var size = ipsubnets[j][1];
        //console.log (ip >> size, subnet >> size, size)
        if ((ip >> size) == subnet >> size) {
            answer.push(ip)
            //console.log (ip,subnet,size)
            continue iploopy;
        }
    }
}

// Get the answer
for (var i=0; i<answer.length; i++) {
    var ip = answer[i]
    //console.log (ip)
    console.log ( ((ip >>24) & 255) + "." + ((ip >>16) & 255) + "." + ((ip >>8) & 255) + "." + ((ip >>0) & 255) )
}

console.log()
console.log(answer.length)
```